# Configure Apache to use SQL Server authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, sql-server, authentication

I believe it's possible to configure Apache to use SQL Server for authentication. You supply the DB connection parameters and a query to run. I suppose the contract is something like:

If the query returns something the user is authenticated, and if the query results are empty, the user is unkown.

Does anyone know how I can configure this?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out for Apache 2.4 on Windows 2012.  I think the changes would be minor for Apache 2.2.

Uncomment the necessary LoadModule lines in httpd.conf:

- authn_dbd_module
- authn_dbm_module
- dbd_module

Make an ODBC connection to the SQL Server:
ODBC Data Source Administrator, System DNS, Add..., Fill in your specific information, and remember the "Name" for later.

Configure authentication in Apache:

```
DBDriver odbc
DBDParams "datasource=<Name here>,user=...,password=..."

<Location /secure>
   AuthType Basic 
   AuthName "Secure Area" 
   AuthBasicProvider dbd
   Require valid-user
   AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT '$apr1$' + PasswordSalt + '$' + Password FROM <your table> WHERE UserName = %s"
</Location>
```

Hope it gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if mssql is supported. Maybe if you add it to pam and then go through that.
mod_auth_mysql is for mysql, mod_auth_pgsql for postgresql and mod_auth_dbi for generic db intefrace.

Comment: what's the pam ?